# Checking for existence of OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ou

How can I check for the existence of an organizational unit without using the `[adsi]::Exists()` method? I can't for the life of me get it work on my system.

Comment: Have you tried `Get-ADOrganizationUnit`?

Comment: I've tried and struggled with it. The documentation tells me little of use. It's too technically written, it assumes that you already understand it.

Comment: [This article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617236.aspx) gives nice examples of its use.  `If (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity 'OU=Europe,CN=Users,DC=corp,DC=contoso,DC=com') {'It exists!'}`

Comment: What does "CN=Users" mean?

Comment: [Here's a good breakdown for you](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977992.aspx)

Comment: The problem here is that when it exists, it moves into the if-statement, but when it doesn't it spits out a nasty error.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Exists()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.exists.aspx) method requires an [LDAP URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746384.aspx) as its argument:

```bsh
$ou = 'ou=foo,dc=example,dc=com'
[adsi]::Exists("LDAP://$ou")
```

If you want to use the `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` cmdlet instead: use the `-Filter` parameter rather than the `-Identity` parameter. The former is usually more forgiving with AD cmdlets:

```bsh
$ou = 'ou=foo,dc=example,dc=com'
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "distinguishedName -eq '$ou'"
```